# UINavigationController with `prefersLargeTitle` set to true doesn't show large title right away - You have to scroll up for it to show

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller, preferslargetitles

I have a fundamental question: I have a `UINavigationController` set as the secondary view of a `UISplitViewController` and I set its `prefersLargeTitle` property to true:

`self.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true`

As the `rootViewController` of that `UINavigationController` I have some arbitrary `UIViewController` containing a `UICollectionView` or something (just some scrolling content).

The problem now is that the large title is not being display right away. You have to scroll up to reveal it first.

Here's an example of the behavior:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FwTU.jpg

I feel like there's a simple property I'm missing here. Any ideas?

The demonstration video is from an example project for the `XCoordinator` framework that I happened to have open. I've recreated this behavior in a new project as well, so it shouldn't matter.

Thanks!